# NFTABLE issue: IPv6 does not behave like IPv4 with mirror config

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, ipv6, nftables

I have an issue with IPv6 on my server. I have nginx configured to listen on port 443 from IPv4 and IPv6. And it works great: my webiste is available form Internet with TLS enabled.

Things get complicated when I activate nftables: **when I am accessing my website from IPv4 it works, but when I access it from IPv6 connections time out :(**

Output of `sudo nft list ruleset`:

```
table inet filter {
        chain INPUT {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
                meta nftrace set 1
                ct state established,related accept comment "allow established connections"
                iif "lo" accept comment "allow all from localhost"
                iif != "lo" ip daddr 127.0.0.0/8 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop comment "drop connections to loopback not coming from loopback"
                iif != "lo" ip6 daddr ::1 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop comment "drop connections to loopback not coming from loopback"
                iifname "tunnel0" accept comment "allow all from VPN"
                udp dport 12345 accept comment "allow VPN on port 12345"
                tcp dport { 22, 80, 443 } accept comment "allow HTTP, HTTPS and SSH on classic ports"
        }

        chain OUTPUT {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        }

        chain FORWARD {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        }
}
```

Output of `sudo nft monitor trace | grep 443`:

```
trace id 76d7cb1a inet filter INPUT packet: iif "eth0" ether saddr AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA ether daddr BB:BB:BB:BB:BB:BB ip6 saddr 2a01:cb09:804b:cd61:CCCC:CCCC:CCCC:CCCC ip6 daddr 2001:CCCC:CCCC:CCCC::CCCC ip6 dscp cs0 ip6 ecn not-ect ip6 hoplimit 45 ip6 flowlabel 0 ip6 nexthdr tcp ip6 length 40 tcp sport 53184 tcp dport 443 tcp flags == syn tcp window 22240
```

Note I do not have this issue with ssh on port 22. I am running `nftables v0.9.8 (E.D.S.)` on Debian 11.

I almost spent a day looking for the solution. Any help is welcome! Thank

Comment: I don't see a rule that allows ICMPv6 for neighbor discovery. Does `ip -6 neighbor` show your IPv6 gateway as "reachable" and with the correct MAC address?

Comment: Yes this it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing some key IPv6 rooting elements. Addind this statement solved my issue:

```
nft add rule inet filter INPUT 'icmpv6 type { 134, 135, 136, 137 } accept'
```

more info at https://serverfault.com/questions/1078828/nftable-issue-ipv6-does-not-behave-like-ipv4-with-mirror-config